# Finding minimum value of $x^2+y^2+xy+x-4y+9$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> What is the minimum value of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy+x-4y+9$ ?

I tried completing squares,

$$x^2+y^2+xy+x-4y+9=\frac12(x^2+2xy+y^2+x^2+2x+1+y^2-8y+16+1)=\frac12[(x+y)^2+(x+1)^2+(y-4)^2+1]$$But not sure how to continue.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I submitted this as an answer. I advise you to look into the hessian.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Comment: You used the tag `multivariable-calculus` which suggests that you would like to use calculus methods. This should work. Take partial derivatives and set them simultaneously equal to zero to find critical point(s). Then, use the second derivative test to verify that minimum occurs at the critical point(s).

Comment: If you want to do this algebraically, make the substitutions $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$, which will eliminate the mixed term. Then complete the squares in $u$ and $v$ independently.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks a lot! It is a clever idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**\begin{align}f(x+y,x-y)&=3x^2-3x+y^2+5y+9\\&=3\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\left(y+\frac52\right)^2+2\end{align}

Comment: What's the motivation behind plugging in $x+y$ and $x-y$?

Comment: @ConnorGordon The fact that$$(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2+(x+y)(x-y)=3x^2+y^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your work is already very useful. Since the function is continuous and bounded from below (your calculations show that the expression is greater or equal than $\frac 12$), it has a global minimum. Since this is a differentiable function in an open set, this global minimum must be a stationary point, i.e.
$$
2x +y +1=0, \quad 2y + x-4 = 0.
$$

So, the global minimum is attained at $(-2,3)$. The minimum is 2.